# How can I get a value from an attribute inside a tag

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have a soup object like:

```
<a class="love-action js-add-to-favorites" data-id="415953" data-price="715.00" href="#">
</a>
```

I did

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml') #передаем переменную в суп
price = soup.find(class_='col-5 col-sm-4 col-lg-7 mob-position detail-top-actions').find('a', class_='love-action js-add-to-favorites')
print(price)
```

I'd like to get only: `715.00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to fix?

You can access attributes of a tag by treating it like a dictionary - So simply get the value from the attribute `data-price` by:

```
price['data-price']
```

#### Example based on your question

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml') #передаем переменную в суп
price = soup.find(class_='col-5 col-sm-4 col-lg-7 mob-position detail-top-actions').find('a', class_='love-action js-add-to-favorites')
print(price['data-price'])
```

#### Output

```
715.00
```